# How To Delete A Record if It is Missing From the Parameters of a PUT Request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way, but conceptually this seems right to me.

I have a Recipe model with a RecipeIngredient model association.

When a user updates their Recipe/RecipeIngredients I want them to be able to remove one of the ingredients from the form, send the PUT request, which will delete all of the RecipeIngredients not present in the request. Simultaneously I want the controller  to either update any modified models, and leave alone any untouched ones.

The request parameters look like this

```
"recipe"=>{"id"=>67, "name"=>"Rice", "genre"=>"Staples", "recipe_ingredients_attributes"=>[{"id"=>32, "ingredient_name"=>"Rice", "measurement_unit_quantity"=>2, "measurement_unit_type"=>"cup", "recipe_id"=>67}, {"id"=>33, "ingredient_name"=>"Water", "measurement_unit_quantity"=>"1", "measurement_unit_type"=>"cup", "recipe_id"=>67}], "instructions_attributes"=>[{"id"=>33, "content"=>"Boil", "recipe_id"=>67}, {"id"=>34, "content"=>"Eat", "recipe_id"=>67}], "user_id"=>1}, "id"=>"67"}
```

And let's say the realize they don't want water, they would remove that chunk of the form and the front end sends a PUT with the following parameters

```
{"recipe"=>{"id"=>67, "name"=>"Rice", "genre"=>"Staples", "recipe_ingredients_attributes"=>[{"id"=>32, "ingredient_name"=>"Rice", "measurement_unit_quantity"=>2, "measurement_unit_type"=>"cup", "recipe_id"=>67}], "instructions_attributes"=>[{"id"=>33, "content"=>"Boil", "recipe_id"=>67}, {"id"=>34, "content"=>"Eat", "recipe_id"=>67}], "user_id"=>1}, "id"=>"67"}
```

Since "water" is no longer present, I want to delete that RecipeIngredient. Updating any instance works fine, but the update method correctly ignores any RecipeIngredient not in the params.

My #update in the recipes_controller is super simple

```
  def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find_by_id(recipe_params[:id]).update(recipe_params)
  end
```

Should I add some logic that detects if a RecipeIngredient is missing from the params and delete any that are indeed missing, or is there a better Rails way to do this?

Comment: I would always prefer a dedicated `delete` method to remove records from the database over deletion as a side-effect of a `put` call.

Comment: @spickermann, yeah I was thinking about this too and I think I'll just have the remove icon fire off a delete for the RecipeIngredient

Answer (score 0):

The "Rails way" of doing this is trough the usage of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and passing the option `allow_destroy: true`.

After this, you want your update attributes to include a field with the name of `_destroy` and a value on it that evaluates to `true`.

Assuming you have a one to many association between `Recipe` and `RecipeIngredient`

You would would need the following:

#*Recipe.rb*

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Your params to update the recipe with id `1` and delete the ingredient with id `1` would then look like this:

```
params = { recipe: 
  {
    recipe_ingredients_attributes: [
      # This associated record would be deleted
      { id: '1', name: "water", _destroy: 'value_that_evaluates_to_true_here' },
      # This associated record would be kept/updated   
      { id: '2', name: "tomatoes" }
    ]
  }
```

NestedAttributes docs: [Here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)